# sudo apt-get ros-groovy-joystick-drivers [sudo] password for liqiming: E: Invalid operation ros-groovy-joystick-drivers

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo apt-get ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
[sudo] password for liqiming:
E: Invalid operation ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/108046/sudo-apt-get-ros-groovy-joystick-drivers-%5Bsudo%5D-password-for-liqiming:--e:-invalid-operation-ros-groovy-joystick-drivers/) by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2013-12-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2013-12-07**:
BTW: your tags say *fuerte*, while you're trying to install *groovy* packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> sudo apt-get ros-groovy-joystick-drivers

You're missing the *install* operation. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter_pan_lqm](https://answers.ros.org/users/9651/peter_pan_lqm/) on 2013-12-08**:
thank you .i figure out the mistake